# What is the shortcut to go (or bring up/maximize the window) to the newest notification in the taskbar?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar, notifications

What is the shortcut to go to the newest notification program in the taskbar?

[image]

So when I hit the combination my skype chat windows with the person who messaged me comes up? (or a installer that finished installing)

It is really annoying when you are messaging with 30 people and you have to search for the yellow marked one who sent you new messages :(

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> key. Win plus any number will activate that program. If its not launched, it will do so. This will work with the first 9 programs, so reorder your programs if you need this changed.

Additionally, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> can be used to cycle to the most recent used open programs. Hold down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key and press tab a few times (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> can be used to move the other direction) and release <kbd>ALT</kbd> once you selected the application you want to switch to.

Alt-tab should also work with individual grouped windows. If skype uses the tabbed interface, then you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to cycle through the active tabs.

Comment: I know about the [win]+[2] shortcut, also alt+tab doesn't show if any application notified me with the yellow color. I want to directly open up the window who notified me last

Comment: Windows does not offer a "switch to the last notification window" shortcutkey.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to switch between windows you can use **"ctrl+alt"**

For skype message popup set skype in compact view.

> View -> Compact View

Also you can set to open new chat in new window from

> Tools >> Options  IMs and SMS >> IM Settings   Click Show Advanced
>   Options   Check Open a New Window When I Receive a New Message in
>   Compact View   Save.

Comment: This is not really about skype, I have many more programs which notify me